# Filter text file with another text file

Tags: php, file

I have got two text files and I need to filter file1 with file2 and put the results in file3.

file1:

```
1232131-72-427-Q john johnson -----more data----------more data-----
8765438-43-542-T peter dudeson -----more data----- -----more data-----
3456761-21-742-G frank zena -----more data----------more data-----
0924560-23-124-O marin franklin -----more data----------more data-----
2345333-21-423-P pin dudeson-----more data----------more data-----
5434225-21-983-A chow ching -----more data----------more data-----
```

file2:

```
8765438-43-542-T
0924560-23-124-O
5434225-21-983-A
```

file3 (expected output):

```
8765438-43-542-T peter dudeson-----more data----------more data-----  
0924560-23-124-O marin franklin-----more data----------more data----- 
5434225-21-983-A chow ching-----more data----------more data-----
```

So basically it has to check the numbers + character from file2 in file1 and delete all the lines that do NOT match and keep the full lines that do match and put them into file3.

I hope someone helps me with this, because I'm stuck on it for way too long now. (BTW: It has to be done without the use of the `explode()` function)

Comment: Is this one of them silly tasks. "You cannot use explode" you write to an answer below. Please state clearly what you want.

Comment: "because im stuck on it for way too long now" — this seems absurd from your question. See what I mean, you are not explaining what you are asking.

Comment: You can improve your question by actually showing what you have tried and where you got stuck. So we can better help you and explain how to solved the problem / and or why you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you can't use `explode()`, but this should work for you:

First we get the two files into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), which looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1232131-72-427-Q john johnson -----more data----------more data-----
    [1] => 8765438-43-542-T peter dudeson -----more data----- -----more data-----
    [2] => 3456761-21-742-G frank zena -----more data----------more data-----
    [3] => 0924560-23-124-O marin franklin -----more data----------more data-----
    [4] => 2345333-21-423-P pin dudeson-----more data----------more data-----
    [5] => 5434225-21-983-A chow ching -----more data----------more data-----
)
```

Then we filter the first file with the second one by using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Where we go through each line and check if the substring to the first space from a line in file one is in the array from file two.

Example:

```
Substring which we want to get with substr(), until the first space
┌──────┴───────┐
8765438-43-542-T peter dudeson -----more data----- -----more data-----
                ↑
Getting the position of the first space with strpos()
```

```
Now checking with in_array() if the substring,
which we got is in the array from the second file

               8765438-43-542-T
                      ↓
Array ( [0] => 8765438-43-542-T [1] => 0924560-23-124-O [2] => 5434225-21-983-A )
```

If the substring is in the array, we will return true and keep the full line in our result array.

At the end we just save our array into a file with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array with new lines.

Code:

```
<?php

    $input = file("PATH/TO/file1", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $filter = file("PATH/TO/file2", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $result = array_filter($input, function($line)use($filter){
        if(in_array(substr($line, 0, strpos($line, " ")), $filter))
            return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    });

    file_put_contents("PATH/TO/file3", implode(PHP_EOL, $result));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in linux, simple paste the script in command:

```
for filter in `cat file2`;do grep $filter file1 ; done > file3
```

Comment: dont have linux available :(

Answer (score 0):

Split each file into an array (by new line) and if the first (before the first space) is not in the second, remove it:

```
$file1 = "1232131-72-427-Q john johnson -----more data----------more data-----
8765438-43-542-T peter dudeson -----more data----- -----more data-----
3456761-21-742-G frank zena -----more data----------more data-----
0924560-23-124-O marin franklin -----more data----------more data-----
2345333-21-423-P pin dudeson-----more data----------more data-----
5434225-21-983-A chow ching -----more data----------more data-----";

$file2 = "8765438-43-542-T
0924560-23-124-O
5434225-21-983-A";

// Get each row of file1 & file2 as arrays.
$rows1 = explode("\r\n", $file1);
$rows2 = explode("\r\n", $file2);
$result = $rows1;

foreach ($rows1 AS $key => $row) {
    // If the text before the first space is not a value in the $rows2 array, delete it.
    if (!in_array(substr($row, 0, strpos($row, ' ')), $rows2)) {
        unset($result[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

You may need to amend the exploding delimiter to `\n` instead of `\r\n` depending on your host.

Hopefully this gives you an idea of how to solve this as well as a solution.

Comment: it has to happen without the explode function :(

Comment: Out of curiosity ... why?